# Dask: Disagreeing Indices After Writing/Reading from Parquet

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, dask

I have a pandas DataFrame, `df`, that I turn into a Dask DataFrame, `dask_df`:

```
import pandas as pd
import dask.dataframe as dd
df = pd.DataFrame.from_dict({'col1':[1,2,3], 'col2':[2,3,4]})
dask_df = dd.from_pandas(df, npartitions=1)
```

I inspect `dask_df`'s index after turning it *back* into a pandas dataframe and see:

`dask_df.compute().index # RangeIndex(start=0, stop=3, step=1)`

However, if I write my dask dataframe to parquet and then read it back into a dask dataframe from parquet, the indices no longer agree:

```
dask_df.to_parquet('dask_df.pq', write_index=True)
test_df = dd.read_parquet('dask_df.pq')
test_df.compute().index #Int64Index([0, 1, 2], dtype='int64', name='index')
```

I'd like to be able to write my dask dataframe (only one partition) to parquet, read it from parquet, and get the original dask dataframe with the same index back.  Any thoughts on what I'm doing incorrectly here?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

It looks like there are two differences between what you provided and what you got back:

1. The name has changed from `None` to `"index"`
2. The type has changed from RangeIndex with the values [0, 1, 2] to type Int64Index with values [0, 1, 2]

In both cases this is because Parquet doesn't provide these options.  All columns must be named with text names in the Parquet file format, and they have no notion of typed columns.